# Updating an application with native installers by cmd?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have build an application with flash builder, and released a native installer.

I could install the file in the silent mode by cmd using -silent argument and -location.

However, I couldn't Update it when I released a newer version, even using the regular installer will give me the choices, however, using cmd gave me no options.

How could I update an application silently using cmd?

Comment: More details may help here.  How are you trying to update it?  What is "the regular installer"? What are "the choices" that the regular installer gives you?  When using cmd what are the options you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You cannot use the silent installer option to update an installed AIR
>   application. This is because the AIR installer cannot determine
>   whether the version to be installed is newer than the installed
>   version, and it would pose a security risk to downgrade the
>   application.

This is the quote from documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/redist/WS485a42d56cd19641-70d979a8124ef20a34b-8000.html

You still can replace swf of your application manually(with some other installer or batch file) if it is acceptable for your case.

---

**Update:**

It seems that you can silently uninstall and then reinstall your app instead of using update:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/redist/WS485a42d56cd19641-70d979a8124ef20a34b-8000.html#WS485a42d56cd19641-70d979a8124ef20a34b-7ffa